# how to add product edit link on product name in admin grid

Tags: magento2

hello everyone I want to add product edit link on product name which is showing in admin grid 
below code is for the display product name 
index.xml

```
<column name="entity_id" class="Magneto\SampleRequest\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products"> 
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array"> 
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array"> 
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> 
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products Name</item> 
        </item> 
        </argument> 
        </column>
```

products.php

```
<?php
      namespace Magneto\SampleRequest\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
    use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
  use\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
  use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
  use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
   class Products extends Column
       {
      protected $_ProductRepository;
  public function __construct(
     ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
   ProductRepositoryInterface $ProductRepository,
    array $components = [],
     array $data = [])
       {
      $this->_ProductRepository = $ProductRepository;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, 
   $data);
   }
       public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
       {
if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
    foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as $key => $items) {
        $product = $this->_ProductRepository->getById($items["entity_id"]);
        $dataSource['data']['items'][$key]['entity_id'] = $product->getName(); //to get product name
    }
}
return $dataSource;
    }
     }
```

now i want to display product edit link on product name click
[image: as you can product name is displaying]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update both files

**index.xml** with below code

```
<column name="entity_id" class="Magneto\SampleRequest\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products"> 
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array"> 
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array"> 
            <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> 
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products Name</item>
        </item> 
    </argument> 
</column>
```

and **products.php** with below code

```
    <?php
namespace Magneto\SampleRequest\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
    use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
    use\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
    use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
    use \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
    class Products extends Column
   {
        private $urlBuilder;
        const PRODUCT_URL_PATH_EDIT = 'catalog/product/edit';
        protected $_ProductRepository;
        public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $ProductRepository,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [])
        {
            $this->_ProductRepository = $ProductRepository;
            $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
            parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, 
            $data);
        }
        public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
        {
            if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
                foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as $key => $items) {
                    $product = $this->_ProductRepository->getById($items["entity_id"]);
                    $dataSource['data']['items'][$key]['entity_id'] = html_entity_decode('<a href="'.$this->urlBuilder->getUrl(self::PRODUCT_URL_PATH_EDIT, ['id' => $product->getId()]).'">'.$product->getName().'</a>');
                }
            }
            return $dataSource;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: not working in my module

Comment: you getting any error after updating above code ?

Comment: no page not found is coming

Comment: try to check with executing compile and cache flush command

Comment: Undefined variable: item in /var/www/html/magento230/app/code/Magneto/SampleRequest/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Products.php on line 31 this error is coming

Comment: OK check my updated answer update products.php file

Comment: please edit your answer add semicolon in line no 3 and remove semicolon from line number 31 that is inner semi colon other code is write